# Standalone blender to X export script

Tags: 3d, blender

I look for a standalone script which can export from a blender file with one single Mesh to an arbitrary 3d format (.dae, .obj, .ply, ...).

The deeper problem is, I have a directory with lots of .blend files and I want a little script which can export automatic them to the 3d files. Otherwise I would have to open each of these files in blender and export manually.

Environment:

- Archlinux
- Blender 2.64

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find a link to ready made script here. Probably try to write your own using the Python API and post issues encountered(if any) here.

Answer (score 2):

Its really simple to write blender python scripts:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="blabla.blend")
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="blabla.obj")
```

save this script as script.py
and run script from commandline

```
blender -P script.py
```

thats basically it.

Comment: I am on macOS, and I would like to import the bpy library. I'm totally new to python and blender : where should I put the blender lib, and where should I write my code ?